# One drive api token not getting the right scope

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I registered an app through the azure portal and have the following permissions added to the delegated user.

[image]

I am using the following api endpoints to get the code and the token:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
```

while requesting the code I am calling this url (line breaks for readability):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=client_id&
response_type=code&
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&
scope=Files.ReadWrite.All
```

This gives the code alright. And I am hitting a POST endpoint with the following details:

```
url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Data:
client_id=client_id
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080
client_secret=secret
grant_type=authorization_code
code=code_from_prev_step
response_type=code
scope=Files.ReadWrite.All
```

I am getting the token alright. But the scope of that token is not what I had requested.

```
{
   "token_type": "Bearer",
   "scope": "Files.Read.All User.Read",
   ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am out of my wits figuring this out.
I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Could you try to use https://jwt.io/ and check what scope(s) are in the token. If there are two Files.Read.All User.Read or only Files.ReadWrite.All?

Comment: While sending request through URL you should get the login prompt and then after credeential insertion are you getting consent popup?

Comment: I have followed the same steps as you did and getting the expected output both in scope and checked the scope in token as well and `Files.ReadWrite.All` is there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was facing was because when I first created the app it only had the read permission. I changed it later to readwrite.all. But for some reason, since I had already agreed on allowing reads and not readwrite, it was not giving me the readwrites I needed.

I simply deleted the app and created a new one with readwrite.all permission and it works as expected now.